# Continuity equation for a charged particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, conservation-laws, charge, dirac-delta-distributions

I am trying to prove the continuity equation for a charged particle moving with some speed v. So, I start with the charge density and current density as,

\begin{align}
\rho(x,t) & = q\delta(x-vt) \\
J(x,t) & = q v \delta(x-vt)
\end{align}

It seems that one would have to take a derivative of the delta function to prove the continuity equation. How does one take such a derivative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity equation for charge and current densities of an accelerated point charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178166/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), like Dirac's delta, are defined by how they act on smooth functions. Since this is a physics site, I will use integral notation instead of a more fancy mathematics notation.

Dirac's delta distribution is defined by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, f(x) \, dx = f(0).
$$

The derivative of a distribution $u$ is defined by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u'(x) \, f(x) \, dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \, f'(x) \, dx.
$$

Therefore,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta'(x) \, f(x) \, dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, f'(x) \, dx = -f'(0).
$$

But you don't need to know the exact definition to do your exercise. You only need to know that you can take the derivative and that the chain rule works (at least in this case):

$$
\partial_t \rho = \partial_t \left(q \delta(x-vt)) \right)
= q (-v)\delta'(x-vt)
= -\partial_x\left(qv\delta(x-vt)\right)
= -\partial_x J
$$
so
$$
\partial_t \rho + \partial_x J = 0.
$$